# Wrap comma separated text on page in span tags with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a number of comma separated values in divs on my page like this:

```
<div class="frequency">
Within 48 hours,Annually
</div>

<div class="frequency">
First 2 weeks,Annually
</div>

<div class="frequency">
Annually
</div>
```

I am trying to wrap each value in a span tag. I have managed to do this, but it will only work on the first one, and then repeats the same values for the rest:

```
var frequencylabels = $('.frequency').html().split(',');
$('.frequency').empty().append(frequencylabels.map(i => `<span class="label">${i}</span>`));
$('.frequency span').unwrap();
```

How can I achieve this output?

```
<span class="label">Within 48 hours</span><span class="label">Annually</span>

<span class="label">First 2 weeks</span><span class="label">Annually</span>

<span class="label">Annually</span>
```

Here is a [JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qx15enm4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop your class and use `split()` / `append()` method inside loop.

Example:

```js
$('.frequency').each(function(index, element) {
  var frequencylabels = $(this).text().split(',');
  $(this).empty().append(frequencylabels.map(i => `<span class="label">${i}</span>`));
  $('.frequency span').unwrap();
});
```

```css
.label {
  background-color: green;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="frequency">
  Within 48 hours,Annually
</div>

<div class="frequency">
  First 2 weeks,Annually
</div>

<div class="frequency">
  Annually
</div>
```

Comment: I have learned something new, Thank you!